# How to display unicode in SVG?

Tags: unicode, svg

An information stored in SVG format in the database. 
If the data contains text it will be displayed as Unicode.

It is necessary to correctly display the SVG files in the browser.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="header" 
viewBox="654.0519483 -714.4517 356.4000564 252">
<defs></defs><g id="0" visibility="visible">
<text id="gText_11081308229940" name="-1" x="790.251953" y="-631.9517"  
font="Arial"  rotate="0" horizAnchor="middle" vertAnchor="middle" scale="4,4" width="1"            stroke="0x000000"> 
\u0048\u0045\u004C\u004C\u004F\u0020\u0057\u004F\u0052\u004C\u0044\u0021\u0021\u0021\u0021        </text> 
</g></svg>
```

When I try this code I get displayed Unicode instead of letters.

Comment: Your encoding is already unicode (`encoding="UTF-8"`), so why do you feel the need to insert what look like JavaScript escape characters?

Comment: I get them from the database in such way and I can*t change the way how characters are stored there.

Comment: Then convert them to actual character data.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you really want to insert Unicode values rather than just choosing the right encoding and putting the characters directly in there, use entities like you would in [any other XML document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_reference_overview):

```
    <text id="gText_11081308229940" name="-1" x="790.251953" y="-631.9517" font="Arial" rotate="0" horizAnchor="middle" vertAnchor="middle" scale="4,4" width="1" stroke="0x000000">&#x0048;&#x0045;&#x004C;&#x004C;&#x004F;&#x0020;&#x0057;&#x004F;&#x0052;&#x004C;&#x0044;&#x0021;&#x0021;&#x0021;&#x0021;</text>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/JPUq4/).

Comment: And encoding="UTF-8" is not right for \u0048 ? Wich encoding will be OK for this?

Comment: @adelak What is leading you to believe that UTF-8 is not "right" for `\u0048`?  It doesn't sound like you understand the difference between Unicode code points and character encodings.

Comment: What I can*t understand that why I can*t display it in browser if encoding is ok. And why i need to replace `\u0048` with `&#x0048` for this.

Comment: @adelak Here is a UTF-8 encoded representation of the `\u0048` Unicode code point: H.  Here are the Unicode code points for the UTF-8 encoded data you're adding to your document instead of that single character: `\u005C\u0075\u0030\u0030\u0034\u0038`.  `\u0048` is just a string of characters in an XML document, `&#x0048` is an XML entity representing a Unicode code point which the browser replaces with a correctly encoded character.

Comment: "\u0048" is how you represent a unicode character in Javascript.  "&#x0048" is how you do it in XML and HTML (SVG is an XML based format).

Answer (score 3):

Just for the case that any future visitor would care. This \u0048 or this &#x0048; are not “a Unicode(s)”. Unicode is standard explaining how to encode binary values to characters to be displayed. The notations above are more exact the Unicode escape sequences of characters. They are useful when you have no option to enter Unicode characters directly. (Their use within the example in the original question is pointless.) There are many of them and you should not mix them. You can look for example at this page: http://billposer.org/Software/ListOfRepresentations.html

Comment: The link is dead.