# how to get unicode in svg

Tags: svg, unicode

this is the first line in my .svg image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

this is inside head part of .php file:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

this is checked in Notepad++ - Encoding menu:

```
Encode in UTF-8 without BUM
```

or (I tried):

```
Encode in UTF-8
```

Still, my img does not display unicode character !?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display unicode in SVG?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134995/how-to-display-unicode-in-svg)

Comment: @BeyelerStudios not sure that's a duplicate, as that question is asking about embedding hex codes and this question *appears* to ask about embedding UTF-8. Although without any sample SVG code it's hard to know for sure.

Comment: Yep, you need to highlight an example coming from your server.

Comment: How you generate your svg and maybe post some signs you wanna include in there.